# Apache 2.2 'a2dissite default' not removing access to its document root

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I've just installed a fresh install of Apache 2.2 on Raspian / Debian, in order to host exactly one site over SSL.

So, before anything, I used `a2dissite default` to remove the default site being served on 80 from `/var/www/`.

I then added my new site to `/var/www/mysite` and created an entirely different config file for this site, using SSL on 443, and enabled it with `a2ensite`.

HOWEVER, after a `sudo service apache2 reload`, while my new site works as expected on port 443, I'm still able to access the 'default' site on port 80, which, as the new site is a subfolder of the default directory means the new site is available at http://domain/mysite

I cannot find anywhere where a default site/directory is configured other than in the default config file, which does NOT appear in `sites-enabled` (only the new site config does).  (And if I edit the default config but leave it in sites-available the changes are not picked up, suggesting that is not where apache is discovering this config.)

So, where is apache picking up the `/var/www` directory on port 80?  Is it a hardcoded directory should nothing override it?  In order to get round this I have had to re-enable the default site, but change the directory to point to somewhere outside of my new site to avoid providing non-SSL access.

Comment: For an unrelated reason I had to reinstall the entire server, so to check here I disabled the default site before making any other changes. Literally installed Apache, then disabled the default site so that sites-enabled was empty. But, the default web root was still available! So, I don't know where this is configured or how to actually disable it (maybe compiled into Apache by default).

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now! trying a2dissite 000-default which is removed successfully from sites-enabled but the even after the site is still available while I only want ssl. Did you find out?

Comment: I did not solve it, so had to work around with setting root folders.  Basically in the end I changed the default non-SSL site to point to a different root (like `var/www/default`) and enabled it.  This had the effect of overriding wherever the *other* default was coming from so the SSL site was not accessible as a subfolder from 80.  Wasn't happy about it though.  Guess there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Yes that is what I ended up doing as well. In your case you can also remove Listen 80 from ports.conf if you are on debian 8.